# Symfony3 - Logout path generation method

Tags: php, symfony, session, twig

What's the difference between using `path('logout')` and `logout_path()` in a Symfony application?

Comment: i guess logout_path() return the relative url for logout route

Comment: @MélikZarkouna In fact, there's a `logout_url()` also, and you can use `url('logout')`. It's strange, seems duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `path('logout')` you call [`RoutingExtension::getPath`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/RoutingExtension.php#L44). Route with name `'logout'` can point to whatever URL you define – e.g. to `'/lorem-ipsum'` and call whatever controller's action – e.g. `DefaultController::loremIpsumAction`.

When you use `logout_path()` you call [`LogoutUrlExtension::getLogoutPath`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/LogoutUrlExtension.php#L39), which generate logout URL for current firewall using [`LogoutUrlGenerator`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3.4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Logout/LogoutUrlGenerator.php).

Comment: So it is better to use `logout_path()` instead of `path()` ?

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux of course it is. Logout path don't need to be defined as route – see this [`security.yml`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NZ4o.png) config and this [template error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Euw7.png).

Answer (score 1):

path :

```
{{ path(name, parameters = [], relative = false) }}
```

path returns the relative URL (without the scheme and host) for the given route. If relative is enabled, it'll create a path relative to the current path. More information in Linking to Pages , in your case `/logout` is your route and i suggest you read about Routing more to understand its components and purpose .

Read Routing to learn more about the Routing component [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html%22Routing%22).
Since Symfony 2.7 you can use `logout_path`

```
{{ logout_path(key = null) }}
```

key is optional and its type is string 
`logout_path` Generates a relative logout URL for the given firewall. If no key is provided, the URL is generated for the current firewall the user is logged into.